# MARS for big data

Tags: r, regression, large-data, splines, mars

Is there a way in which MARS/EARTH can work with ff objects or big data?

I need an additive model for a sample of size 20000 and around 100 variables. I can not work with that dimension with a RAM so I need to find another option to work with big data.

Answer (score 1):

Earth will easily handle your 20 thousand by 100 matrix.  That model requires less than a quarter of a gig of memory.

The inst/slowtests/test.big.R file in the earth test suite has a model with 6 million by 100 matrix (tested on a machine with 32 GB of memory).

Earth doesn't have facilities for ff (and similar) objects, because the limit in practice is model building time rather than memory.